WordPress PHP script not correctly being called by Javascript
I've redacted some info that's not relevant.
I have a WordPress site and I've made a plugin meant for updating a database I've created. To put it simply I have a tool and I want to limit the amount of times a user can use that tool. So to do this I created a database with a user id and usage count column. I have another script which checks this database and if the usage column is a certain amount it won't let the user use the tool and that works fine.
The issue I am facing is when I open the link to the plugin in the browser that's https://REDACTED.com/wp-content/plugins/track_user_usage/track_user_usage.php it gets the user id and updates the database successfully with no problem but when I try and make it request the php script from a simple javascript/html script I created for a test it says success but doesn't update the database.
Here is my PHP plugin with some stuff redacted:
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Track User Usage
Plugin URL: REDACTED
Description: 
Version: 1.0
Author: REDACTED
*/

define('DB_SERVER2', 'REDACTED');
define('DB_USERNAME2', 'REDACTED');
define('DB_PASSWORD2', 'REDACTED');
define('DB_NAME2', 'REDACTED');

// Establish a persistent database connection
$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER2, DB_USERNAME2, DB_PASSWORD2, DB_NAME2);
$conn->autocommit(TRUE);
$conn->real_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

// Checking connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Database connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

function process_request() {

    global $conn;

    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        define( 'ABSPATH', '/home/REDACTED/REDACTED.com/' );
    }

     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET') {
     
        return;
    }

    include_once ABSPATH . '/wp-load.php';
    $userid = get_current_user_id();

    if ($userid == 0) {
        return;
    }

    $user_id = $userid; 
    $created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

    // Check if the user already exists in the table
    $sql_check_user = "SELECT * FROM tool_usage WHERE user_id = ?";
    $stmt_check_user = $conn->prepare($sql_check_user);
    $stmt_check_user->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt_check_user->execute();
    $result = $stmt_check_user->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // User exists, update the usage count
        $sql_update_usage = "UPDATE tool_usage SET usage_count = usage_count + 1 WHERE user_id = ?";
        $stmt_update_usage = $conn->prepare($sql_update_usage);
        $stmt_update_usage->bind_param("i", $user_id);
        if ($stmt_update_usage->execute()) {
            
        } else {
            
        }
    } else {
        // User doesn't exist, insert a new record
        $usage_count = 1; // Initial usage count
        $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO tool_usage (user_id, usage_count, created_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt_insert = $conn->prepare($sql_insert);
        $stmt_insert->bind_param("iis", $user_id, $usage_count, $created_at);
        if ($stmt_insert->execute()) {
            
        } else {
            
        }
    }

    $stmt_check_user->close();
}

process_request();

$conn->close();
?>

If you are wondering why there are some else statements with nothing there it's because there was echo statements but those were causing some issues for some reason so I just deleted them because I don't really need them, but they were saying success.
And here is my simple test HTML/Javascript code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Track User Usage</title>
    <script>
        function trackUserUsage() {
            fetch('https://www.REDACTED.com/wp-content/plugins/track_user_usage/track_user_usage.php')
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.success) {
                        console.log('PHP script called successfully:', data);
                    } else {
                        console.error('PHP script error:', data);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error calling PHP script:', error);
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="trackUserUsage()">Track User Usage</button>
</body>
</html>


I've tried a bunch of different ways for the Javascript and PHP for the past few hours with no success.

The only condition your PHP ever returns anything to the JS is the case when your DB connection fails. Your JS is testing for a .success element in the response, but that is never set in your PHP (even in the case of DB failure).  You need to return something to the JS to indicate what happened in the PHP.

It's really bad practice to use a platform and then intentionally sidestep that platform when there is absolutely no need to. Consider researching ajax hooks like wp_ajax_* or post back options using query args. You will have much better control and can do things like nonce your requests to protect your website and your users.

@Lawrence makes an interesting point but  wp-ajax is very 2010s, it predates widespread fetch adoption. Adding rest api endpoints is probably a far more sane and modern approach

@pguardiario I don't see how fetch makes wp_ajax_* hooks obsolete.

Not fetch so much as the rest api.. In the old days we passed xml back and forth. This was before json was even a thing. So just to break down AJAX (Async Js And Xml) - all modern js is async,,'js and' we can ignore... And xml is completely obsolete in 2024.

@pguardiario I think you misunderstood what wp_ajax_* hooks are.

@gre_gor agree to disagree I guess. I use wp hooks but you won't catch me using those ajax ones since 2019 or so.

@pguardiario there's never been a requirement to use Xml with wp_ajax hooks. I'm not disagreeing with your decision to use the rest endpoints but Xml has nothing to do with the wp_ajax, nor, technically, does it have anything to do with obsolescence. Not ideal for most APIs, but Xml is still useful for some situations that are not easily handled with json.

@lawrence, I get what you're saying but json simply hasn't been around (as a widely used standard) for nearly as long as those wp_ajax hooks. The x in ajax is for xml, I'm sure you don't want argue that point. Rest API is a more modern alternative in general.

@pguardiario - nomenclature aside including the fact that ajax has javascript in it when there's 0 requirement to use javascript with wp_ajax endpoints, is there any difference in an HTTP request to a wp_ajax endpoint vs a rest endpoint? From the requestor's side, there's no difference aside from cleaner URLs.

Thanks for the help everyone I used the rest api endpoint and nonce and some cookie thing and all is working well.
I used this in the PHP script + some other changes to the main function
function set_nonce_cookies($request) {
    $cookie_name = 'rest_nonce';
    $cookie_value = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');
    $cookie_exp = 0;
    $cookie_path = "/";
    $cookie_domain = "";
    $cookie_secure = true;
    $cookie_http_only = false;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_exp, $cookie_path, $cookie_domain, $cookie_secure, $cookie_http_only);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'set_nonce_cookies');

function register_track_user_usage_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route('wp/v2', '/track-usage', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'track_user_usage',
    ));
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_track_user_usage_endpoint');


function track_user_usage($request) {
    $nonce = $request->get_header('X-WP-Nonce');
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'wp_rest')) {
        return new WP_Error('rest_forbidden', 'Invalid nonce.', array('status' => 403));
    }

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        return new WP_Error('rest_forbidden', 'User is not logged in.', array('status' => 403));
    }

    $userid = get_current_user_id();

    if ($userid == 0) {
        return new WP_Error('unauthorized', 'User is not logged in', array('status' => 401));
    }

    $response_data = array(
        'nonce' => $nonce
    );
    
    // Rest of code

And I used this for the Javascript:


function trackUserUsage() {
            const url = 'https://www.REDACTED.com/wp-json/wp/v2/track-usage';
            const nonce = Cookies.get('rest_nonce');

            fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-WP-Nonce': nonce
                },
                credentials: 'include'
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        }




This isn't how fetch works, maybe you're thinking of axios. Consider this:
fetch(url).then(response => {
  if(response.status === 200){
    response.text().then(html => {
      console.log(html)
    })
  }
})

